# Can't pass arguments to chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a simple chrome extension. There is a [**pageAction**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)'s default icon that should appear on the pages with a specific URL (`http://www.example.com/*`).

There is a two file

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon" : "images/icons/19.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeContent"
  ]
}
```

**`background.js`**

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
            {
                // rule1
                conditions : [
                    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                        pageUrl : {urlPrefix : 'http://www.example.com/'}
                    })
                ],
                actions    : [
                    new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()
                ]
            },
            {
                // rule2
                conditions : [
                    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                        pageUrl : {queryContains : 'q1=green'}
                    })
                ],
                actions    : [
                    new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({
                        path : {"19" : "images/icons/green.png"}
                    })
                ]
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

`rule1` should show pageAction's icon and `rule2` should change icon to green version on the pages with URL that looks like `http://www.example.com/?q1=green`

But during installation of extension things come to:

```
Error in response to events.removeRules: Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property '.0': Value does not match any valid type choices.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dug deeply into this error, and it seems like the documentation does not reflect well the fact that using `path` parameter is not implemented. This is certainly a bug, tracked [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=462542).

For now, to fix this you need to load the image and convert it to ImageData format before calling `SetIcon`.

```
// Takes a local path to intended 19x19 icon
//   and passes a correct SetIcon action to the callback
function createSetIconAction(path, callback) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,19,19);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,19,19);
    var action = new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({imageData: imageData});
    callback(action);
  }
  image.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(path);
}

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
  createSetIconAction("images/icons/green.png", function(setIconAction) {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      /* rule1, */
      {
        conditions : [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl : {queryContains : 'q1=green'}
          })
        ],
        actions    : [ setIconAction ]
      }
    ]);        
  });
});
```

If needed, this can be generalized to support high-DPI icon (19 + 38):

```
function createSetIconAction(path19, path38, callback) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var image19 = new Image();
  image19.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image19,0,0,19,19); // fixed
    var imageData19 = ctx.getImageData(0,0,19,19);
    var image38 = new Image();
    image38.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(image38,0,0,38,38);
      var imageData38 = ctx.getImageData(0,0,38,38);      
      var action = new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({
        imageData: {19: imageData19, 38: imageData38}
      });
      callback(action);
    }
    image38.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(path38);
  }
  image19.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(path19);
}
```

Comment: since you say it *can* be generalized - would you be so kind to add that code? I'm afraid I cannot come up with a solution and the bug doesnt seem to be fixed any time soon

Comment: @JörnBerkefeld Done, though it's probably not elegant, and not tested.

Comment: thanks a bunch - tested it with various ways of writing the parameter to SetIcon but it seems to be not implemented (or we just dont know how)

Comment: An alternative is to use `declarativeContent.RequestContentScript` to inject a content script that makes a call back to the background page to update the icon.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you can use `new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path:'yourPath.png' })`,
No need to specify size `path: {"19": "images/icons/green.png"}`, its default value is: 16
Use `declarativeContent.SetIcon` need to pay attention to a problem, it is actually a bug.

Actual use of `path` will eventually be automatically converted to ImageData.

**see screenshot:**

[image: action.imageData]

**The root cause of the error of `declarativeContent.SetIcon` is: it is an asynchronous API, but at the same time it has no asynchronous callback. The only thing you can do is wait.**

```js
const action = new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path: 'assets/icon.png' });
console.log(action.imageData); // =>  undefined
```

**see screenshot:**

[image: undefined]

```js
// invalid
new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path: 'assets/icon.png' }, action => console.log(action));
```

It takes a while to wait:

```js
const action = new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path: 'assets/icon.png' });
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(action.imageData); // {16: ArrayBuffer(1060)}
}, 5);
```

**see screenshot:**

[image: setTimeout]

When you understand the reason for the error of `SetIcon`, the problem will be solved well.
You only need to put the operation of `addRules` in the event.

**onInstalled event**

```js
const rule2 = { id: 'hideAction', conditions: [...], actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path: 'assets/icon.png' })]};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule2]);
  });
});
```

**pageAction.onClicked**

```js
const rule2 = { id: 'hideAction', conditions: [...], actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path: 'assets/icon.png' })]};

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  if (condition) {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(['hideAction']);
  } else {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule2]);
  }
});
```

There are some related information:

`SetIcon` source code

```js
declarativeContent.SetIcon = function (parameters) {
  // TODO(devlin): This is very, very wrong. setIcon() is potentially
  // asynchronous (in the case of a path being specified), which means this
  // becomes an "asynchronous constructor". Errors can be thrown *after* the
  // `new declarativeContent.SetIcon(...)` call, and in the async cases,
  // this wouldn't work when we immediately add the action via an API call
  // (e.g.,
  //   chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChange.addRules(
  //       [{conditions: ..., actions: [ new SetIcon(...) ]}]);
  // ). Some of this is tracked in http://crbug.com/415315.
  setIcon(
    parameters,
    $Function.bind(function (data) {
      // Fake calling the original function as a constructor.
      $Object.setPrototypeOf(this, nativeSetIcon.prototype);
      $Function.apply(nativeSetIcon, this, [data]);
    }, this)
  );
};
```

Discussion of related issues:
http://crbug.com/415315

Comment: From the link, apparently this bug has a status of WontFix since 2016.

Answer (score 1):

### No solution

As the guys before me mentioned, this is a bug. There are no solutions, only workarounds.

### Workarounds

#### #1: Draw icon using canvas

As [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan) described in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28765872/2016383) already.

#### #2 Wait for icon load (timeout hack)

Thanks to [weiya-ou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9854149/weiya-ou)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302205/2016383) I realized that I can just wait for the async icon data transformation to finish.

```
// Make your handler `async`
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
  const action = await new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({
    path: {
      19: 'images/19.png',
      38: 'images/38.png',
    },
  })

  // THE WAIT STARTS

  // Wait max. 10 loops
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Create a promise
    const checkAvailability = new Promise((resolve) => {
      // Resolve promise after 100ms
      setTimeout(() => resolve(!!action.imageData), 100)
    })

    // Wait for the promise resolution
    const isAvailable = await checkAvailability

    // When image available, we are done here
    if (isAvailable) break
  }

  // THE WAIT ENDS

  const condition = new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
    pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'my.page.net' },
  })

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [condition],
        actions: [action],
      },
    ]);
  });
});
```

#### #3 Use `chrome.tabs`

You would need the `tabs` permission (as said [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/)).

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, { status }, { url }) => {
  // Only check when URL is resolved
  if (status !== 'complete') return

  // What is our target page?
  const isOurPage = url?.match(/my\.page\.net/)

  if (isOurPage) {
    // Show active icon
    chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
      path: {
        19: 'images/19.png',
        38: 'images/38.png',
      },
      tabId,
    })
  } else {
    // Show inactive icon
    chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
      path: {
        19: 'images/19-inactive.png',
        38: 'images/38-inactive.png',
      },
      tabId,
    })
  }
})
```