# How do you call arbitrary functions using addRules with declarativeContent listeners in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change an extension I'm working on from a browser action to a page action. Currently, the extension detects a tab change and, if the URL of the tab is on our domains, makes a request for JSON data for status information, so it can make the good icon or the bad icon appear as a status indicator. My browser action code was this:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab) {
        var url = tab.url,
            matches = url.match(/(domain1)|(domain2)\.com/g);

        if (url && matches) {
            // Query for JSON data and change the icon based on it.
            loadReach(url);
        } else {
            // Change the icon bad
        }
    });
});
```

I have the basic listeners in place to insert the declarativeContent listener and show the initial icon, but am unsure where to put my callback that makes the query for the JSON data:

```
// When the extension is installed or upgraded ...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostContains: 'domain1.com' },
          }),
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostContains: 'domain2.com' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

Where in the second codeblock would I be able to run that callback, or is it not supported by this method?

Comment: Page actions are apparently about to be gone as a separate entity and will be just the same as toolbar icons due to the extension toolbar redesign. I don't have any in Chrome 48 dev. See https://crbug.com/403823

Comment: I think the point of rules is that all the logic is fixed, to make it much faster. You can't add dynamicism (?) to it.

Comment: @wOxxOm you ever come across information like this and think "Man, it would be nice if the docs mentioned this is being phased out." ?

Comment: @wOxxOm Aaw man, Canary doesn't have page actions either. Why did they do that?? The cookie icon is still there. Very useful location.

Comment: Well, I'm disappointed as well, however the API should work for the foreseeable future in my opinion in order not to break thousands of existing extensions. Anyway as for the question I think all that's needed is [chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28765872/3959875)

Comment: Google tests the behavior using Chrome fieldtrials with its random user selection. To disable the new behavior use `--force-fieldtrials="*ExtensionActionRedesign/Disabled"` in Chrome command line.