# chrome.PageAction.hide(tabId) not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to show my extension icon enabled only if the URL equal *xyz* and the web-page has a specific DOM element.

**It is going to look a lot, but actually only because chrome extension need lots of code and files, I think it is a beginners question as I'm new to chrome-extensions**

I'm trying to solve it by message sending when the dom is ready:

At my content script -

```js
//sending false at load time
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({enableIcon: false});

// * bla bla bla code when dom is ready, i send message to enable it
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({enableIcon: true});
```

Then my BG script get the message and that what it does:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

 // disable/enable action
 showHideActionIcon(request.enableIcon);

}); //on message
```

some more code that might help ...

```js
async function showHideActionIcon(isToShow) {   
    var tabId = (await getCurrentTab()).id;

    if (isToShow) {
        console.log('showing');
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    } else {
        console.log('hiding');
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
} //showHideActionIcon


function getCurrentTab() {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            var currTab = tabs[0];
            if (currTab) {
                // tab found, return it
                resolve(currTab);
            } else {
                // exception!
                reject('no tab is active:(');
            }
        }); //tabs.query

    }); //new Promise
} // getCurrentTab
```

Lastly my manifast.json if needed

```js
{
"name": "ok",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "yeah",

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://goodSite*"],
    "js": ["dom/main.js"]
  }
],

"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background/main.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

"page_action": {
  "default_icon": {
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  }
},
"icons": {
  "128": "images/get_started128.png"
},

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Well nothing happens, I can see in the console that 'hiding' is written but that  the icon is not disabled.

I think that I do a lots of things wrong, because even my getCurrentTab() function get rejected sometime (why?, you know what, ignore the why, just when it does not get rejected, why is my icon is not hidden/disabled)

Comment: Pass sender.tab.id inside onMessage listener and use it instead of using chrome.tabs.query because the content script runs in any matching tab, not just the active one.

Comment: Also, your content script already runs after DOMContentLoaded when the DOM is ready, it's the default timing so you don't even need to disable pageAction.

Comment: I think it helps a bit, now I always have my tabId, But, chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId) has no effect. The icon is still shown and enabled.
I can see in my console that it write 'hidding', so it get there allright... any idea?

Comment: hide() doesn't actually hide the icon, it just dims it, so you don't need it at all. You may want to specify a different looking "default_icon" in manifest.json, then use chrome.pageAction.setIcon in addition to show() to specify the enabled icon.

Comment: It actually does not seems dimmed at all. I tried to link to the icon images (before after hide, but not enough reputaion)

Comment: When  I do not surf at https://goodSite (from manifest.json matches) it does get gray out. isn't suppose to be the same gray when called hide()?

Comment: one last thing, I added on click listener to the icon and it is working only when it is shown (does not work after hide even though the icon looked enabled)

Comment: show() enables the html, yes, and hide() disables it. If you want to have it always available maybe you should switch to browserAction instead.

Comment: "It actually does not seems dimmed at all" we seem to be going in circles and I suspect you're still using both hide() and show() so of course hiding won't change anything as it's superseded by show().

Comment: I want the icon to look as it disabled . I want to it to be available only on one page only when this page get this one message. 
Hide does not change the color of the Icon to be disabled. (it looked disabled when mach the role as expected. Does changeIcon is the only solution?

Comment: Yes, draw a different icon (or change the original one's transparency in an editor) and use setIcon().

Comment: "we seem to be going in circles ", I guess I don't understand hide() and show() correctly :(( sorry :( Do you have any advice to solve my problem? :(

Comment: "Yes, draw a different icon" OK I thought I can change it via hide() and show()
thanks!! write an answear and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as expected, and seems to be a flaw in Chrome pageAction documentation.

What you need to do is to use `setIcon` in order to set disable state:

```
 chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
                tabId: tabId,
                path: "icons/dimmed.png"
            }, () => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShowPageAction` has a higher priority than `pageAction.hide`, so `pageAction.hide` cannot overwrite `ShowPageAction`, you need to remove it first.

The icon will still not turn gray after removal, but the click function of the icon is no longer available.

```js
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules([rules[0].id], () => {
  chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
});
```

In fact, `pageAction.hide` will only work on non-matching addresses, and the color of the matching address icon will not change, but the click function is disabled.

[image: pageAction.hide]

Another way is to set a gray icon, `chrome.pageAction.setIcon` or `declarativeContent.SetIcon`.

`declarativeContent.SetIcon` is more recommended because it requires fewer permissions and is faster.
If you choose to use `declarativeContent.SetIcon`, you need to pay attention to another issue ([Can't pass arguments to chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302205/9854149)), because it will make you less detours.