# Chrome Extension V3 Set Icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My extension should change its icon on specific sites. I had a solution with Manifest 2 - don't get it how to do that with v3. It's always displaying the icon specified in the manifest under "action" / default Icon (gray.png):

**Manifest (v3):**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
  "permissions":[
                  "declarativeContent",
                  "activeTab",
                  "tabs",
                  "storage",
                  "scripting"
                ],
  "host_permissions":[
                      "<all_urls>"
                     ],
  "action" :
  {
    "default_icon" : "/images/gray.png",
    "default_title" : "Test"
  }

}
```

**background.js**

```
let rule1 = {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { hostSuffix: '.google.com'},
      })
    ],
    actions: [ 
        new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({ path: '/images/red.png' })
    ]
  };

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule1]);        
  });
```

Comment: Problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750081/cant-pass-arguments-to-chrome-declarativecontent-seticon/64302205#64302205 Workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750081/cant-pass-arguments-to-chrome-declarativecontent-seticon/66956075#66956075